# jQuery: How to add float values in multiple fields using class name

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, addition

Using jQuery, I have float values in fields with similar class names "**score**"and I just want to make a function that will add all float values in those fields and assign the result to "**field5**".

```
<input id="field1" type="text" class="score">2.5</input>
<input id="field2" type="text" class="score">6.02</input>
<input id="field3" type="text" class="score">1</input>
<input id="field4" type="text" class="score">4.03</input>
<input id="result" type="text" class="result"></input>
```

I made the script below but it doesn't work even though the function executes.

```
$(.score).on('change',function(){
    var total = 0
    $(this).each(function(){
       total += this.value;
  });
});
    $('#result').val(total);
    });
```

Comment: I finally figured it out. Thanks guys!

function getResult(){
  var total = 0;
  
  $('.score').each(function(){
 var checkval= parseFloat(this.value);
 if(!isNaN(checkval)) total += checkval;
  });  
  $('#result').val(total.toFixed(2));
}

Answer (score 1):

Lot of issues in your code:

**JS:**

```
$(".score").on('keyup', function () {
    var total = 0
    $(".score").each(function () {
        total += parseFloat(this.value);
    });
    $('#result').val(total);
});
```

**HTML**

```
<input id="field1" type="text" class="score" value="1"/>
<input id="field2" type="text" class="score" value="1.2"/>
<input id="field3" type="text" class="score" value="1.4"/>
<input id="field4" type="text" class="score" value="3.1"/>
<input id="result" type="text" class="result" value=""/>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/GCu2D/839/

1. input is a self closing tag. You should use it like in this example
2. You should iterate on `$(".score")` instead of `$(this)` to get all input values. Latter will give only the current input's value.
3. Use parseFloat to convert the string type into float. By default you get string value from the `.value`. In order to add them, you need to convert them to float
4. Your selector `$(.score)` is invalid. Use `$(".score")` .
5. `$('#result').val(total);` should be inside the event handler.

Comment: Not inside the iteration, but inside the event function as you have placed it.

Comment: @ErikE. Yeah. Modified it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured it out. Thanks guys!

```
function getResult(){
  var total = 0;

  $('.score').each(function(){
    var checkval= parseFloat(this.value);
    if(!isNaN(checkval)) total += checkval;
  });  
  $('#result').val(total.toFixed(2));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I believe .change() is used with dropdowns. Try using `.keydown()` to detect a change in an input box.

There are a few errors in your code -

```
var total = 0;
```

Semicolon is missing.

```
$('#result').val(total);
```

This will assign the value and will not show it. If you wish to display teh value as well, use

```
$('#result').append(total);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $(".score").on('change',function(){
                var total = 0.00;
                $(".score").each(function(){
                    if(undefined != $(this).val() && "" != $.trim($(this).val()))
                        total += parseFloat($(this).val());
                });
                $('#result').val(total);
            });

        });
```